# remove \n from dictionary value swift

Tags: json, swift, string, dictionary, decode

I have dictionary [String : String], key "header" has value with another values. and I want to remove this symbols "\n", ""

```
"header": "{\n ephemeralPublicKey = \"xxxxx\";\n    publicKeyHash = \"xxxx\";\n    transactionId = xxxx;\n}", "version": "EC_v1", "signature": "xxxxxxx"
```

this "header" one key of my dictionary.

```
["header": "{\n    ephemeralPublicKey = \"xxx\";\n    publicKeyHash = \"xxx\";\n    transactionId = xxx;\n}", "version": "xxx", "signature": "xxx", "data": "xxx"]
```

i also need the header not to be a string but to be { }

so, my structure this:

```
["header": "{\n    ephemeralPublicKey = \"xxx\";\n    publicKeyHash = \"xxx\";\n    transactionId = xxx;\n}", "version": "xxx", "signature": "xxx", "data": "xxx"]
```

I want to make  lie this:

```
{
      "data":"xxx",
      "signature":"xxx",
      "header":{
         "publicKeyHash":"xxx",
         "ephemeralPublicKey":"xxx",
         "transactionId":"xxx"
      },
      "version":"xxx"
   }
```

[image]

I get

```
let data = payment.token.paymentData
```

next I do:

```
guard let token = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any] else {
            return
        }
```

and take this:

```
elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : "version"
        - value : xxxxx
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : "signature"
        - value : xxxxxxxx
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : "data"
        - value : xxx
      ▿ 3 : 2 elements
        - key : "header"
        ▿ value : 3 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : publicKeyHash
            - value : xxx
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : ephemeralPublicKey
            - value : xxx
          ▿ 2 : 2 elements
            - key : transactionId
            - value : xxxx
```

but I need to take this structure:

```
{
   "paymentData":{
      "data":"xxxx",
      "signature":"xxxxx",
      "header":{
         "publicKeyHash":"xxx",
         "ephemeralPublicKey":"xxx",
         "transactionId":"xxx"
      },
      "version":"xxx"
   }
```

next time i do it:

```
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: token, options: [])

        guard let string = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\/", with: "/").replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "") else { return }
```

and after that my values ​​remain without "" quotes.

Comment: Modify your string before decoding, bu using [`replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences)

Comment: @HunterLion this string inside dictionary, as a value one of the keys. how to modify before decoding?

Comment: How did you get the header string in the first place?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson data comes in random order.

Comment: Sorry, you misread what I meant with first place. I meant what is the origin of that string, do you get it as a string or is it converted from something?

Comment: You're relying on `(NS)Dictionary` description while you want JSON, right? The `\n` is not the issue, it's the `;` and the `=` which are... Show the whole process on how you are getting that output, it's all wrong here.

Comment: Never mind, it looks like Larme figured it out.

Comment: added come code down @Larme

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of misunderstanding what it is you are trying to achieve here...it sounds as if what you're interested in is using "standard" [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) Swift objects to convert `Data` into Swift objets.

To do so:

- You create Swift structs for each layer of your JSON elements
- Next you use a `JSONDecoder` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder) to decode raw `Data` into your data structure.

Here is how that looks

### Create Decodable Swift Structs

If this is your JSON structure:

```
{
    "paymentData": {
        "data": "longdatastringhere",
        "signature": "alsolongstring",
        "header": {
            "publicKeyHash": "Ibq...",
            "ephemeralPublicKey": "MFK....",
            "transactionId": "2779..."
        },
        "version": "EC_v1"
    }
}
```

You can create Swift structs for each of your JSON objects like so

```
struct PaymentDataContainer: Decodable {
    let paymentData: PaymentData
}
```

`PaymentData` is another Swift struct you need to create

```
struct PaymentData: Decodable {
    let data: String
    let signature: String
    let header: PaymentHeader
    let version: String
}
```

`PaymentHeader` is...yes you guessed it... another Swift struct that you need to create

```
struct PaymentHeader: Decodable {
    let publicKeyHash: String
    let ephemeralPublicKey: String
    let transactionId: String
}
```

### Use JSONDecoder to Decode Your Data

Assuming your JSON data which you mentioned here:

`let data = payment.token.paymentData`

is raw `Data` you can decode it like so

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let paymentDataContainer = try jsonDecoder.decode(PaymentDataContainer.self, from: data)
    // You now have a Swift struct you can work with as normal
    print(paymentDataContainer.paymentData.version) // prints "EC_v1"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```